# image take up no width

Tags: html, css

I need help making my image take up no width on the HTML. What I mean by this is when you shrink the width size of the window, I don't want the image affecting the horizontal slider. I would think overflow:hidden; would work but the right side of the image takes up space on the HTML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `max-width: 100%` to the `img` element. In doing so, the `img` will never take up more than `100%` of the width of the parent element.

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use `max-width: 100vw` (which is `100%` of the browser width's width).

```
img {
  max-width: 100vw;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a width: 50%; instead of px. Play around with which % value best corresponds to your image width. That way the image will automatically adjust to the browser windows size.